# Selecting a record based on user input in mysql

Tags: mysql, select, input, reference, relation

I have three tables

`games (ga_id , game)` ,

`equipments (eq_id, equipment)`,

`games_equipments (ga_id, eq_id)`.

The `ga_id` references the that `ga_id` of the games table and the `eq_id` references the `eq_id` of the equipments table.

the table have the following sample data:

```
games table: (1,basketball) , (2, baseball), (3, tennis)
equipments table: (1, A) (2,B) (3,B)
games_equipments table: (1,1) (1,2) (2,1) (2,3) (3,1)
```

These are the things that i wanted to do:
1.  If I input eq_id 1 and 2 that will return basketball because that is the only game that uses both eq_id 1 and eq_id 2

1. If I input `eq_id` 1 that will return tennis only because that is the only game that uses the sole equipment 1. Though basketball and baseball both use `eq_id` 1 but each need other equipments in order to be played. So basketball and baseball should not be returned
2. If I input `eq_id` 3 that will not return anything because though there is a game that uses eq_id 3 which is baseball but it still needs `eq_id` 1 in order to be played.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should join your table and filter the result with HAVING keyword :

```
SELECT games.game, COUNT(games.ga_id), ga_eq.eq_id FROM `games`
       JOIN ga_eq USING (ga_id) 
       JOIN equipements USING (eq_id)  
       GROUP BY games.ga_id 
       HAVING COUNT(games.ga_id)=1 AND eq_id=1
```

Here is the method :
Get all row with

```
SELECT games.game,  ga_eq.eq_id FROM `games` 
         JOIN ga_eq USING (ga_id) JOIN equipements USING (eq_id)
```

result :
[image]

Then grouby ID and make a count a number id (so number equipement)

```
SELECT games.game,  ga_eq.eq_id, COUNT(games.ga_id) FROM `games` 
      JOIN ga_eq USING (ga_id) JOIN equipements USING (eq_id) 
      GROUP BY  games.ga_id
```

[image]

Then use HAVING keyword to keep only games with one equipement and put your eq_id filter IN HAVING CLAUSE (not in WHERE clause)

```
SELECT games.game,  ga_eq.eq_id, COUNT(games.ga_id)
       FROM `games` JOIN ga_eq USING (ga_id) JOIN equipements USING (eq_id) 
        GROUP BY  games.ga_id HAVING COUNT(games.ga_id)=1  AND eq_id=1
```

Result :
[image]

Change the filter `AND eq_id=3`  -> empty result

For many equipment id the query is a little bit different,
I try to make one generic but didn't fint out, if someone else have an idea ?

```
SELECT g.game, equipements.eq_id, (
                                  SELECT COUNT( eq_id ) FROM ga_eq
                                  WHERE ga_id = g.ga_id
                                   AND eq_id IN (1, 2)
                                  ) AS nb_eq
                 FROM  `games` g
                 JOIN ga_eq USING ( ga_id ) 
                 JOIN equipements USING ( eq_id ) 
                 GROUP BY game
                 HAVING nb_eq =2
```

You have to change `AND eq_id IN (1, 2)` AND `HAVING nb_eq =2` to change the input

Comment: thanks a lot for your help. You did a very good job explaining in detail how this query solves my problem.

Comment: Hi Marcassin, what about if my inputs are eq_id 1 and 2 and the expected return should be ga_id 1 which is basketball, What should be the query?

Comment: @user2322606 just edited the answer. Find a generic function could be a good training.